# Difference between Queue and Sets Python

Tags: python, multithreading, set, queue

In case there is multi-threads and one function which adds a value to a list and another function which takes that value. What would the difference be with:

```
import queue
scrape = queue.Queue()
def scrape():
    scrape.put('example')
def send():
    example = scrape.get()
    print (example)

scrape = set([])
def scrape():
    scrape.add('example')
def send():
    example = scrape.pop()
    print (example)
```

Why do people use the queue module which is 170-180 lines with if conditions slowing the process for this situation if they can use sets which also gives them the advantage of duplicates filtering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Queues` maintain ordering of possibly non-unique elements. `Sets`, on the other hand, do not maintain ordering and may not contain duplicates.

In your case you may need to keep a record of each thing scraped and/or the relative order in which it was scraped. In that case, use `queues`. If you just want a list of the unique things you scraped, and you don't care about the relative order in which you scraped them, use `sets`.

As `@mata` points out, a `queue` should be used if multiple threads are producing and consuming to/from it. `Queues` implement the blocking functionality  needed to work with producer/consumer `threads`. `Queues` are thread-safe, `sets` are not.

In this example from the docs:

```
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
     t = Thread(target=worker)
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()

for item in source():
    q.put(item)

q.join()   # block until all tasks are done
```

`get` in the consumer thread (i.e. `worker`) blocks until there is something in the `queue` to get, `join` in the producer thread blocks until each item that it put into the `queue` is consumed, and `task_done` in the consumer thread tells the queue that the item it got has been consumed.

Comment: That's only one reason, more compelling are the synchroning features of a queue, blocking access, possibility to limit size, etc...

Comment: What do you mean by blocking access? Checking if the queue is empty or not? I simply use try and except with continue inside while true loop.

Comment: `get`, by default, blocks until something has been put in the queue and is available to be gotten. Much more Pythonic than raising an exception to indicate that the `queue` is empty.

Comment: If you look inside get definition there is a try statement inside of it. And also a lot of if and else statements.

Comment: By "definition" of `get` are you referring to its source code? If so, let Python worry about the `trys` and the conditions etc. and just use the readable, tested, robust, Pythonic `get` method

Comment: I was debugging it with my program and it was having a lot of duplicates in an unusual amount since yesterday( Using 20-30 threads ), check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223923/need-consumer-and-producer-with-duplicate-filter-python I have now switched to not using queue and I can not say how much the performance of my program has improved and its usage.

Comment: OK I read your other thread and I see what you are trying to do. Check out the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581895/how-check-if-a-task-is-already-in-python-queue?noredirect=1&lq=1 which subclasses `Queue` to ensure that an item is not added to the `queue` more than once.

Comment: Well, thanks you and Stackoverflow for pointing me in the right direction every time.